# Random number shows up in cross-reference

Tags: tables, hyperref, cross-referencing

I'm looking to cross-reference a table located in the appendix while inside the section before the appendix.

When I do this, however, it says "Tabelle 2 6" instead of the desired "Tabelle 2". I don't know why there is a "6", or how to get rid of it. I don't have 6 tables. How can I change it so it's "Tabelle 2"?

```
\hyperref[Tabelle 2]{Tabelle 2 \ref*{Tabelle 2}}

\section*{\Large APPENDIX}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 \label{Tabelle 2}
```

Comment: Please post a full MWE, not just a few lines of code.

Comment: The `\label` should be *within* the scope of the `table` environment.  What is probably happening here is that it is picking up the most recent other labeled environment, perhaps a section.

Comment: you have labelled the last labelled section so code not shown. it is not random

Answer (score 1):

Some markers were added to make it more readable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Ein}

%\hyperref[Tabelle 2]{Tabelle 2 \ref*{Tabelle 2}}

\setcounter{table}{5}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
AAA
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{eine}
\end{table}

\section{Zwei}

\section*{\Large APPENDIX}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
BBB
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}
 \label{Tabelle 2} 
 
  \ref{eine} %This refers to Table 6
  
 \ref{Tabelle 2} %This refers to Section 2
 
 

  
  \end{document}
```

When you have `\caption` inside `table`, `\ref` gives the right tabular number, but when the caption is outside `table` it refers to the section number (in this case). Now you can see that the numbers are not random, but they have very precise meaning, temporary different from you needs.

[image]

Comment: The `\label` should be inside `table`

Comment: @egreg Yes! Therefore I have shown the result of the wrong usage. I am adding a more clear comment to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I can see three problems with your code.

- First, the `table` *environment* is missing a `\caption` statement. Hence, the `table` *counter* isn't being incremented.
- Second, the `\label` statement that purports to be associated with the table is not inside the `table` environment.

  As a result, LaTeX has no way of successfully associating the label -- "Tabelle 2" -- with the table in question. Instead, the label is getting associated with some counter that happens to have been incremented most recently via an internal `\refstepcounter` directive. This could be almost anything -- a numbered `figure`, a numbered `equation`, a numbered `section`, etc. Do check in your document for some object that's numbered "6"; that would be a leading candidate.
- Third, to create a proper cross-reference to the table, you should -- once you've fixed the issues mentioned above -- also replace

  ```
  \hyperref[Tabelle 2]{Tabelle 2 \ref*{Tabelle 2}}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \hyperref[Tabelle 2]{Tabelle \ref*{Tabelle 2}}
  ```

  i.e., remove the "2" character from `{Tabelle 2`.

  Incidentally, it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve with this rather complicated construct. If your objective is to create a cross-referencing call-out in which both "Tabelle" and "2" are part of the hyperlink, a much simpler method is readily available:

  ```
  \autoref{Tabelle 2}
  ```

---

Here's a sample document that implements these ideas.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

%% two distinct ways to create the same cross-referencing call-out:
\hyperref[Tabelle 2]{Tabelle \ref*{Tabelle 2}}

\autoref{Tabelle 2}


\section*{\Large Appendix}
\addtocounter{table}{1} % just for this example

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Eine \tablename} \label{Tabelle 2}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You’re lucky I’m in tour 